# How can I get a less pixelated screenshot in java?

Tags: java, image, jframe

I am using a `BufferedImage` in java after capturing the image out of a JFrame. **I need some way to sharpen the image such that when it's enlarged it doesn't look so pixelated.** Here's the thing it has to keep the same image size.

Here's the code I'm using to capture the image.

```
    private void grabScreenShot() throws Exception
    {
        BufferedImage image = (BufferedImage)createImage(getSize().width, getSize().height);
        paint(image.getGraphics());
        try{
            //ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File(TimeTable.path+"\\TimeLine.jpg"));
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("C:\\Users\\"+TimeTable.user+"\\AppData\\TimeLineMacroProgram\\TimeLine.jpg"));
            //ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("C:\\ProgramData\\TimeLineMacroProgram\\TimeLine.jpg"));
            System.out.println("Image was created");
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("Had trouble writing the image.");
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

And here's the image it creates
[image]

Comment: I don't use Swing so this may be off. But isn't it working perfectly? Eg capturing at SCREEN resolution (which may be insufficient for your need)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JPG is ill suited for screenshots. It's designed for complex and colorful pictures wherein information loss during compression is nearly negligible, such as photos. For screenshots you should rather be using GIF or, better, PNG.

```
ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("C:\\Users\\"+TimeTable.user+"\\AppData\\TimeLineMacroProgram\\TimeLine.png"));
```

You only end up with a bigger file, but you get pixelperfect sharpness and detail back, which is simply impossible with JPG.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you're writing it out as a JPEG file.

I'd change the format to something non-lossy, or else force the writer to not use compression by accessing and changing its [ImageWriteParam](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriteParam.html).

Comment: Currently the best type of compression that it will allow me